# Bootstrap 5 горизонтальная прокрутка адаптивной таблицы зажатой мышью

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, table

подскажите, где можно почитать, как сделать горизонтальную прокрутку адаптивной таблицы мышью. Читатаю документацию по bootstrap и не могу найти такого решения, хотя кажется, что раньше оно было.
Поясню, что я хочу сделать:
Адаптивная таблица прекрасно перетягивается **на мобильном** устройстве при помощи пальца.
Я хочу сделать возможность зажать курсор мыши на таблице и перетащить ее вправо или влево. Т.е. не использовать скроллбар, а добиться эффекта схожего с пальцем на мобильном устройстве.
Могу предположить, что для этого существует какой-то дополнительный плагин, но у меня не получается его найти.